# How to get a file path in visual studio 2013 solution explorer?

Tags: c#, filepath

I have a .wav file in solution explorer under Data folder. I need to play it via SoundPlayer. When i try to get the file in sound location by "~/Data/xyz.wav" it occours some runtime problem. How to fix the file path?

I tried through this code

```
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer();
player.SoundLocation = "~/Data/spanish_guitar.wav";
player.Load();
player.PlaySync();
```

Manually I created the Data folder in Solution Explorer.

Comment: "It occurs some runtime problem"?! +3!? Seriously, what is happening today in SO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to define the path of project and add file name

```
var projectPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()));
var filePath = Path.Combine(projectPath, "Data", "spanish_guitar.wav");
```